# How to implement adaptive step size Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp?

Tags: ode, runge-kutta, numerical-modelling, numerics, differential-equations

Trying to implement an adaptive step size Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp but failing with this error:

```
home/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:15: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

The ODE i am trying to solve (and using in the example below, transformed from higher order to system of 1st order ODEs) is the following:

$$u''(x)+u(x)+u(x)^3 =0 ~~{\rm with}~~ u(0)=u'(0)=1 $$

Here is the implementation I am using:

```
def rkck(f, x, y, h, tol):
    #xn = x + h
    err = 2 * tol
    while (err > tol):
        xn = x + h
        k1 = h*f(x,y)
        k2 = h*f(x+(1/5)*h,y+((1/5)*k1)) 
        k3 = h*f(x+(3/10)*h,y+((3/40)*k1)+((9/40)*k2))
        k4 = h*f(x+(3/5)*h,y+((3/10)*k1)-((9/10)*k2)+((6/5)*k3))
        k5 = h*f(x+(1/1)*h,y-((11/54)*k1)+((5/2)*k2)-((70/27)*k3)+((35/27)*k4))
        k6 = h*f(x+(7/8)*h,y+((1631/55296)*k1)+((175/512)*k2)+((575/13824)*k3)+((44275/110592)*k4)+((253/4096)*k5))
        yn4 = y + ((37/378)*k1)+((250/621)*k3)+((125/594)*k4)+((512/1771)*k6)
        yn5 = y + ((2825/27648)*k1)+((18575/48384)*k3)+((13525/55296)*k4)+((277/14336)*k5)+((1/4)*k6)
        err = yn4[-1]-yn5[-1]
        h = 0.8 * h * (tol/err)**(1/float(5))
        yn = yn4
    return xn, yn

def integrate_sStepControl(f, t0, y0, tend, h, tol):
    T = [t0]
    Y = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0 
    while (t < tend):
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        t, y = rkck(f, t, y, h, tol)
        T.append(t)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(T), np.array(Y)

def f_1(t,y): 
    return np.array([ y[1], -y[0]-(y[0])**3 ])

Y0_f1 = np.array([1.0,1.0])


# Execution
h = 0.05
tv, yv = integrate_sStepControl(f=f_1, t0=0.0, y0=Y0_f1, tend=100.0, h=h, tol=1.0E-05)
print("[ %20.15f, %20.15f]"%(yv[-1,0], yv[-1,1]) )
plt.plot(tv, yv)
```

Getting the error above, but it gets plotted. Don't know what I am doing wrong here :-/ 
[image: plot]

Comment: If I remember correctly, then you should be able to do timestepping with the first four evaluations already. You could check if those are correct by doing a fixed-stepsize forward simulation and see if it checks out. Then you can add the stepsize control later.

Comment: Somehow I think there's something wrong with my implementatio.. I can't get what is wrong, but it's not working the way it should..

Comment: Perhaps you’re getting the ‘err’ variable value to be 0 sometimes, with respect to finite precision, so you’re getting a division by zero there.

Comment: But the rest of the implementation is right? @spektr

Comment: @ZelelB assuming you wrote the appropriate Butcher Tableau for this method, it seems you’re in the right direction. Maybe check for if ‘err’ equals zero so you don’t risk division by zeros with it. If you still run into division by zero problems, then it is not clear what could cause it.

Comment: Answered at the cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863292/3088138